# How to check if a string is one of the known values?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$a = 'abc';

if($a among array('are','abc','xyz','lmn'))
    echo 'true';
?>
```

Suppose I have the code above, how to write the statement "if($a among...)"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function.

Manual says:

> Searches haystack for needle using loose comparison unless strict is set.

Example:

```
<?php
$a = 'abc';

if (in_array($a, array('are','abc','xyz','lmn'))) {
    echo "Got abc";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
if (in_array($a, array('are','abc','xyz','lmn')))
{
  echo 'True';
}
```

Also, although it's technically allowed to not use curly brackets in the example you gave, I'd highly recommend that you use them. If you were to come back later and add some more logic for when the condition is true, you might forget to add the curly brackets and thus ruin your code.

Answer (score 2):

There is [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function.

```
if(in_array($a, array('are','abc','xyz','lmn'), true)){
   echo 'true';
}
```

***NOTE:***
You should set the 3rd parameter to `true` to use the strict compare.

`in_array(0, array('are','abc','xyz','lmn'))` will return `true`, this may not what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
if (in_array($a, array('are','abc','xyz','lmn')))
{
  // Code
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

> **in_array** — *Checks if a value exists in an array*
>
> bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict =
>   FALSE ] ) Searches haystack for needle using loose comparison unless
>   strict is set.